# How to add trusted SSL certificate to LinuxForHealth FHIR Server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, web, health

I'm currently facing an issue with my LinuxForHealth FHIR Server setup and SSL certificates. I have the FHIR server running as a Docker container on my server, using a self-signed certificate and operating on HTTPS via port 9443.

Simultaneously, I have a website also running on the same server, utilizing HTTPS via ports 80 and 443, with a trusted certificate (with all the .pem files) from Let's Encrypt. My goal is to use the Let's Encrypt certificate for the LinuxForHealth FHIR Server as well.

I've gone through the LinuxForHealth documentation regarding keystores, truststores, and configuring SSL certificates (https://linuxforhealth.github.io/FHIR/guides/FHIRServerUsersGuide/#52-keystores-truststores-and-the-linuxforhealth-fhir-server), but I'm having difficulty understanding how to integrate the certificates from the same domain for the Docker container.

If anyone has experience with LinuxForHealth and SSL certificate management or has successfully integrated trusted certificates for a Dockerized FHIR server, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or step-by-step instructions.

Thank you!

**My current position**

I don't know where to start. I have the .pem files, but in the documentation, it is given that the server asks for .p12 file?